# drop duplicate rows based on some columns in excel using python

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
toclean = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\Desktop\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx',sheetname=0)

df4 = toclean.drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='last')

df4.save(r'C:\Users\Desktop\final.xlsx')
```

I have a sheet in excel which has some info lets say

name    diad    ad  fa

3   23  2   3

2   2   1   1

2   2   3   2

1

now my output should look like

3   23  2   3

2   2   1   1

1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! can you post some sample data? You have told us what it should look like, but you haven't should us what it *does* look like. Are those values all separate columns?

Comment: above is it look's like and the one below is my output

Answer (score 0):

Other than

df4.save(r'C:\Users\Desktop\final.xlsx')

I think the above looks good. Just replace this line with df4.to_excel(NEW FILE NAME)

Comment: it saving but result is not as expected

Comment: You will need to be more specific. What were you expecting and what is the result?